# NewRelic doesn't graph any data in a Python + Gevent based system

Tags: gevent, newrelic

I have a Gevent based backend, where in a set of external apis are called in parallel. NewRelic doesn't report the time consumed by these apis in its UI.

I tried to push these timings myself using custom metrics. Here is the code snippet:

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
instance.getAval()
newrelic.agent.record_custom_metric("Custom/BUS_EXT_CALL", time.time() - t1)
```

This didn't work either. I tried to look into their python agent code and made following changes:

```
def record_custom_metric(name, value, application=None, app_name=None):
    if app_name is None and application is None:
       transaction = current_transaction()
       if transaction:
           transaction.record_custom_metric(name, value)
    elif app_name is not None:
       application = newrelic.api.application.application_instance(app_name)
       application.record_custom_metric(name, value)
    else:
       if application.enabled:
           application.record_custom_metric(name, value)
```

and now `newrelic.agent.record_custom_metric("Custom/BUS_EXT_CALL", time.time() - t1, app_name="ControllerTest")` this call was successful, but somehow the data doesn't appear in NewRelic's dashboard.